# Powershell: Grab the name of the directory before I delete it

Tags: powershell

I would like to grab the name of the directory and write it to a log file before I delete it. Here is what I have so far,

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(0)
$path = "C:\STest\Videos\"
$logFile = "C:\STest\Log\log.txt"

# Delete folders older than the $limit.
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and       $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
Write-Host $file

#Log what we've done
#Add-Content -Path $strLogFile -Value "$(Get-Date) deleted $file"
```

I've tried adding -Name like so:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -name | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

The script runs but $file doesn't hold any information. I think -Name is what I want, I'm just using it in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are piping to Remove-Item which has no output. Split it up like so:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(0)
$path = "C:\STest\Videos\"
$logFile = "C:\STest\Log\log.txt"

# Delete folders older than the $limit.
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and       $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }
$file | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
$file | Select -Expand FullName | Out-File $LogFile -append
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great. One question, what is the purpose of having to repeat $file multiple times?

Comment: The first one assigns the folder listing to the variable. The second one pipes those to the Remove-Item command, and the third one outputs those paths to a file for logging. If this resolves your issue please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I plan on it, there's a timer before doing so :P Thanks again and thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `Tee-Object` e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | 
     Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } |
     Foreach {$_.FullName} | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogFile | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Also if you're on V3 or higher you can simplify to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -Directory | 
     Where CreationTime -lt $limit |
     Foreach FullName | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogFile | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Also, depending on how you want the file to appear in the log you can simplify a bit further:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -Directory | 
     Where CreationTime -lt $limit |
     Tee-Object -FilePath $LogFile | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Dang, I always forget about Tee-Object! Excellent answer, as usual. Is `ForEach FullName` as fast/faster than `Select -Expand FullName`?